# Setup Wi-Fi connection to be used by Wi-Fi devices like my SE Xperia?

Tags: networking, internet, adsl, wireless-networking

I have an ADSL connection and a D-Link Wireless adapter. how can i setup an internet connection to be used by Wi-Fi devices like my SE Xperia ?

Comment: what is the adaptor connected to?

Comment: LAN connection is connected to modem and nothing connected to Wireless Adapter

Comment: its not even connected to a computer? o0

Comment: No, I want to use it as access point or Wi-Fi hotspot

Comment: by adaptor, do you mean an access point (either as a second box attached to your modem) or a USB device connected to something else?

Comment: I just want to use pc internet in my mobile via Wi-Fi, something like reverse tethering

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1990/discussion-between-omid-amraei-and-journeyman-geek)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to share your ADSL connection via the D-Link adapter.
So you access internet with the ADSL link on a computer, and want to turn this computer into a wifi hotspot ?
Please tell more about your installation.
If what I think is right, take a look at :
http://windows.appstorm.net/how-to/turn-your-pc-into-a-wifi-hot-spot/

Comment: Yes that's what i really want to do

Comment: Is there any way to do that without any special application ?

Comment: If you want to do it without any special application, it has to be built in your operating system. What is your OS ?

Comment: Windows Server 2003

Comment: I don't recommend using a server as a wireless access point if the server has some critical data / usage.  
But if you want, you can add Wireless Provisioning Services and configure it the way you like. I am not into it so the configuration is up to you.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15479  
There is the link to microsoft.  
Here is how it works :   
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-understanding-windows-wireless-provisioning-services-wps/5628781